# MP3 audio overlapping in simple Android app

Tags: android, audio, mp3

I have to make an app that, among other things, plays an Audio at the very first moment a user goes to a specific Activity.

The app is just a task list, and whenever a task is created or the button "view tasks" is clicked, that activity will start and, along with it, the song.

Till this point, everything is fine (I think). The idea is that the song goes on being played until **explicitly** the user clicks on the "stop music" button which is just available in the task list activity (the same that made the audio begin).

So, if I go to "Add task", the song goes on. The problem is, of course, that whenever the user goes again into the "Task list" activity, the song starts again, while the previous one actually goes on (This process can be repeated infinite times). When I asked my professor, he said in a really misterious way "use broadcast signals". I have make a couple of stupid things with them (printing a message whenever a signal is correcly received) but I have no idea how that is related to my case. My main code (related with the task list) is:

```
public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();

MediaPlayer onepunchftw;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tasklist, container, false);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasklist);
    final Button stopmusicbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopaudiobutton);
    //final Button gotostartbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
    onepunchftw = MediaPlayer.create(Tasklist.this, R.raw.onepunchmanintro);
    stopmusicbutton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //buttonmusicclicked(v);
                    if (onepunchftw.isPlaying()) {
                        onepunchftw.pause();
                        stopmusicbutton.setText("Resume Audio");
                    } else {
                        onepunchftw.start();
                        stopmusicbutton.setText("Stop Audio");
                    }
                }
            }

    );

    MyDBHandler db = new MyDBHandler(this);

    List<Tasks> task =db.getAllTasks();

    db.getAllTasks();

    ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskList);
    ListAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, ArrayofName);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
    l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Can any of you, by any chance, help me?